# Downloading PersistentConnectionLogging.zip

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know where I can download this profile so that I can put it on my device for push debugging? All internet and stackoverflow links point to here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG6

but the link to download it there is not active and there's no note anywhere on that page that says 'replaced by ....' or 'do this instead...' or whatever. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On that page, click the `Companion File` link in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

As of 17 June 2017 the PersistentConnectionLogging profile provided by Apple at that page has expired, again. However, if you're running an iOS 10 device you no longer need the profile!

With your device connected to your Mac, you can view the APNS logs live in Console or the Xcode device window.

Alternatively, you can [follow these steps (PDF warning)](https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf) to enable sysdiagnose to gather your logs.

Source: [question on Apple dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50768).